# Stained glass window reflection not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, glass, reflection

I'm trying to have my stained glass window cast a colorful reflection onto the ground of my scene. I want a distinct reflection, and the only lights in my scenes are an HDRI image for the World, and a Sun lamp to get the window reflection you see here:
[image]

I'm not sure what to do.
[image]
Textures: https://workupload.com/archive/8uQ3ArXuG2

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images before sharing? File >External Data >Pack Resources

Comment: When I pack them unfortunately its way too big to upload then

Comment: It's not reflections you are talking about if the light goes through the glass. It's called caustics. There can be reflective caustics as well, but you are probably after refractive caustics here. You can look it it up. They are very computationally expensive - be prepared for the render times to increase dramatically.

Comment: So use another platform like workupload for example, only keep the useful objects

Comment: I was about to say what @MartynasŽiemys has just said.. I guess you could save the expense with a reasonable fake, (purpose-built projector) if acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup the image gets lost, maybe make it simpler, like plug the image into the *Transparent* shader and plug the *Transparent* into the *Output*:

[image]